# 'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks' and 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' not working

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, eslint, prettier, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I am trying to setup eslint that can provide me errors and warning in expo react native project.
I added these rules but it seems like they are not working.

This is how my .**eslintrc.js** looks like

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb',
  plugins: ['react', 'react-native', 'react-hooks', 'import'],
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  env: {
    jest: true,
    'react-native/react-native': true,
  },
  rules: {
    'no-use-before-define': 'off',
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'comma-dangle': 'off',
    'padded-blocks': 'off',
    'arrow-body-style': 'off',
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'warn',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn',
    'react-native/no-unused-styles': 2,
    'react-native/split-platform-components': 2,
    'react-native/no-inline-styles': 2,
    'react-native/no-color-literals': 2,
    'react-native/no-raw-text': 2,
    'react-native/no-single-element-style-arrays': 2,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
  },
  globals: {
    fetch: false,
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx ./src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "eslint": "^8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

vs code **settings.json**

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  }
}
```

I have a useEffect hook where I am executing one function and not added as a dependency, it's not giving me any warnings.

```
const deleteGoalHandler = (goalId) => {
    updateGoal((prev) => [...prev.filter((item) => item.id !== goalId)]);
};

  useEffect(() => {
    deleteGoalHandler();
  }, []);
```

It should have given warning.